# Convert a std::vector<boost::optional<double>> to a std::vector<double>

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<boost::optional<double>>`, `foo` say. In this particular instance I need a `std::vector<double>` where any "optional" element in the other vector maps to a 0 in the new one.

Am I missing a one-line solution for this?

The other choice is the unsatisfactory

```
std::vector<double> out(foo.size());
for (auto& it : foo){
    out.push_back(it ? *it : 0.0);
}
```

I'd welcome a solution based on `std::optional`, even though I don't use that standard yet.

Comment: `std::transform` might be used. and `boost::optional::value_or`.

Comment: I'd love to know how ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Trying to craft an answer for that now, but hardly any better. Pretty much just forces the ranged-based `for` into a single long line. You still need to define `out` on the line above.

Comment: *"unsatisfactory"* - I don't see why, really

Comment: [`transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html)?

Comment: @BoBTFish: range-v3 solution would be ok btw: `auto out = foo | ranges::view::transform([](const auto& o) { return o.value_or(0.0); });`

Comment: @StoryTeller: Something like `std::vector<double> out(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(now it gets hard))` would be nicer no?

Comment: @SebastianJohnHoward - No back inserter for the vector's c'tor. But If that's what you want, BoBTFish's comment about the transform_iterator should give you that.

Comment: [OT]: `it` is a bad name, as it is **not** an iterator, but an `optional`.

Comment: Are you sure your example code is good? You are first adding foo.size() elements with 0.0 in the constructor and then adding foo.size() more elements in the loop. (the constructor with int parameter doesn't reserve that space; it actually adds the elements)

Comment: and FWIF, the code in the question is in my opinion 1000 times more readable than the answers, so I'd just use that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::transform` solution:

```
std::vector<double> out(foo.size());
std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), out.begin(), [](const auto& opt){ return opt.value_or(0.0); });
```

Edit: Added the `out` definition.

Comment: This just forces the range-based `for` loop into a single long line, not exactly any tidier. And you didn't define `out`, so you still need an extra line for that.

Comment: @BoBTFish Indeed. But it's as close as you can get to one-line without ranges-v3 I'd say.

Comment: @BoBTFish - It does have one thing over the raw loop. Once the OP switches to C++17, they can parallelise the execution of the transformation with a trivial change to that one line.

Comment: @MaxLanghof So how would it look *with* ranges-v3?

Comment: @ArthurTacca See the comment by Jarod42 on the question itself. Note that it does not give you another vector as-is though (although I'm sure there is an easy way to add that).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks, I missed that

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that constructs the output `vector` with the desired values. Still can't be forced onto one line though.

```
auto valueOrZero = [](auto opt){ return opt?*opt:0.0; };
std::vector<double> out(boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(foo), valueOrZero), boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(foo), valueOrZero));
```

Unfortunately, `boost::transform_iterator` requires the unary transformation function to be specified for the end iterator, and you can't just repeat the lamdba definition because it also requires both iterators to have exactly the same type. This forces the lambda onto its own line.

I think it would be possible to write a transform iterator that works around this, but you'd have to do it from scratch.

Comment: Not sure, but `bind(&optional<double>::value_or, _1, 0.0)` (to replace lambda) might allow one line.